# Redirect after including new page in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, redirect, angularjs-ng-include

I build my own form via ng-include. After you click "okay" on a page, the next one gets included.

HTML index

```
<form>
      <ng-include src="includedForm"></ng-include>
</form>
```

HTML form page 1

```
<input type="submit" value="Okay" ng-click="nextPage('page2.html')">
```

HTML form page 2

```
<section id="sectionOne">
      <input type="submit" value="Okay" ng-click="nextPage('page3.html')">
</section>

<section id="sectionTwo">
      <p>This is the first thing I want to see<p>
</section>
```

AngularJS

```
//default included page:
$scope.includedForm = "page1.html";

$scope.nextPage = function(page){
      $scope.includedForm = page;
}
```

I want the user to get redirected to sectionTwo on the second form page after clicking "okay" on the first page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use ng-switch built in directive
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch